# Posting to Facebook using SLComposeViewController posts to album

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I have added the ability for our users to post to Facebook from within our app.  However,
when users make a post it goes to a selected album.  I do not want to upload an image to the album, I just want to post it as a status update so it appears as a newsfeed.

I do not really know much about posting to Facebook from an App so excuse me if the terminology is wrong.

My Question: How do I post a status update (with an image if possible) rather than having the image appear in the album?

Thanks for the help